# SQLAlchemy not producing proper SQL statement for multi column UniqueConstraints

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

Below are the two different attempts I have made in trying to achieve a multi-column unique constraint in sqlalchemy, both of which seems to have failed since a proper SQL statement is not being produced.

The attempts:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text, ForeignKey, DateTime, create_engine, UniqueConstraint, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.interfaces import PoolListener
import sqlalchemy

class ForeignKeysListener(PoolListener):
    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        db_cursor = dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

engine = create_engine(r"sqlite:///" + r"d:\\foo.db",
                       listeners=[ForeignKeysListener()], echo = True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
ses = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
print sqlalchemy.__version__
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dummy = Column(Integer, unique = True)
class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    baz = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    qux = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    UniqueConstraint("baz", "qux")

class Cruft(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cruft"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    qux = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    __table_args = (UniqueConstraint("bar", "qux"),)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The output:

```
>>> 0.8.2
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("foo")
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("bar")
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("cruft")
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    dummy INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (dummy)
)


2013-05-09 16:25:42,677 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,767 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2013-05-09 16:25:42,769 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE bar (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    baz INTEGER, 
    qux INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(baz) REFERENCES foo (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(qux) REFERENCES foo (id)
)


2013-05-09 16:25:42,769 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,838 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2013-05-09 16:25:42,839 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE cruft (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    bar INTEGER, 
    qux INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(bar) REFERENCES foo (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(qux) REFERENCES foo (id)
)


2013-05-09 16:25:42,839 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-05-09 16:25:42,917 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `UniqueConstraint` in a declarative table configuration, you need to specify it using the [`__table_args__` attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html) (note the underscores on **both** sides of the name:

```
class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("baz", "qux"),)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    baz = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    qux = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))

class Cruft(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cruft"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("bar", "qux"),)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
    qux = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))
```

The attribute *must* be either a tuple or a dictionary.

Creating these two tables now results in:

```
2013-05-09 13:38:44,180 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE cruft (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    bar INTEGER, 
    qux INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (bar, qux), 
    FOREIGN KEY(bar) REFERENCES foo (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(qux) REFERENCES foo (id)
)

...

2013-05-09 13:38:44,181 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE bar (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    baz INTEGER, 
    qux INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (baz, qux), 
    FOREIGN KEY(baz) REFERENCES foo (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(qux) REFERENCES foo (id)
)
```

Also see the [*Setting up Constraints when using the Declarative ORM Extension* section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#setting-up-constraints-when-using-the-declarative-orm-extension) of the *Defining Constraints and Indexes* chapter.

Comment: Forget to add the ending double underscores. Fixing it fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to right after I made the comment but I got something akin to "I can answer the question in 6  minute". And then I forgot :P

Comment: That was confusing, the [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) didn't make it obvious that this had to be in the __table_args__ variable. But indeed it works, thanks.

Comment: @Zitrax: see the [*Setting up Constraints when using the Declarative ORM Extension* section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#setting-up-constraints-when-using-the-declarative-orm-extension); the rest of the docs use the `Table()` class rather than a declarative base, and the way to pass in extra arguments to `Table()` via the declarative base is to use `__table_args__`, hence the name.